# Метод JAVA возвращающий угол по 2 координатам

Tags: java

Если ли класс в java который реализовывает вычисление угла по 2 координатам. В 2-х мерной плоскости.
Сам я э
то могу найти но не хочется каждый раз создавать свою реализацию данной задачи.

Псевдокод:

```
    dx = x1 - x0;
    dy = y1 - y0;
    angle = arccos(dx/dy);
```

Comment: Если можете, добавте код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно вы этот метод имеете в виду

```
Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x1-x2, y1-y2));
```